# Python matplotlib.pyplot in zeppelin notepad

Tags: python, matplotlib, forecasting

When I am trying to plot time series data got below error:

> dataframe contains one datetime index and one values column is float
>   type
>   view limit minimum is less than 1 and is an invalid matplotlib date
>   value

How to resolve this?

Comment: I am getting error for the first time and if ran second time I am getting the plot result. This happens all the times i.e. odd numbers failing and even number success or each alternative run it is success

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problems leading me to this jira bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4096 where developers recommend to use ipython instead of python interpreter for plotting.

try

```
%sh 
pip install jupyter
```

then

```
%python.ipython
# plot here
```

worked for me